# Go to offset on a variable in python

Tags: python

I've opened a file in python which I need to parse out in blocks of 1024 bytes.
So I've read the first 1024 bytes of the file with:

```
file_chunk = file.read(1024)
```

So I got the first chunk in a variable. Now I need to go to offset 16 of that content to search for an hex value, to make some decision on it.
When I need to do that in a file I use the file.seek(position), but that doesn't work for a variable.
How can I go into a specific offset of a variable to compare it? Or else, in each 1024 bytes iteration of the file, how can I go to offset 16 to compare it with something else?

Answer (score 1):

its just a string

```
file_chunk[16:] #16th byte to the end of the string

file_chunk[16] #just the 16th byte

file_chunk[16:20] #4 bytes starting at 16
```

Comment: Thanks, that's it. I've seen that in the past, but now totally forgot, it's my first python code.